# Pandas copy slice warning appears to be inconsistent?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I know there are a million posts about Pandas DataFrame copy slice warning, and I have researched this... but I still don't understand why the warning is NOT called in Line10 below but IS called in Line15 below. Using Python 3.8.3 & pandas 1.0.5

```
import pandas as pd

#### Example DataFrame
myid = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
myorder = [3, 2, 1, 2, 1]
y = [3642, 3640, 3632, 3628, 3608]
x = [11811, 11812, 11807, 11795, 11795]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(myid, myorder, x, y)), 
                  columns =['myid', 'myorder', 'x', 'y']) 
df.sort_values(by=['myid', 'myorder'], inplace=True) ## LINE 10
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

idval =2
tempdf = df[mygdf.myid == idval]
tempdf.sort_values(by=['myid', 'myorder'], inplace=True) ## LINE 15
tempdf.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

`tempdf = df[mygdf.myid == idval]`

Is creating a view called `tempdf` on `df`, the underlying data has not been copied, think of `tempdf` as a pre-recorded filter applied to `df`, and further changes will only be applied to those rows that meet the filter.

This means that if you update `tempdf`, you will be updating `df` - hence the warning.

To avoid the warning you would need to do the following, which forces `df` and `tempdf` to use differing underlying data structures:

`tempdf = df[mygdf.myid == idval].copy()`

Now changes to `tempdf` will have no impact on `df`, so your warning goes away.