# Merging Two DataFrames in Pandas Issues Adding Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following 2 dataframes:

df1 =

| Age | Eye Color |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | Yellow |
| 22 | brown |
| 44 | black |

df2 =

| Age | Eye Color | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | Yellow | 23 |

I need the output:

df3 =

| Age | Eye Color | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | Yellow | 23 |
| 22 | brown | Nan |
| 44 | black | Nan |

I have tried numerous merge attempts but i always get age_x and age_y, etc. The only column I need to add is **"weight"**.

Comment: Perhaps you can add more sample to your question? Because the answer below should have given you the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.merge()` on two intersecting columns:

```py
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=['Age', 'Eye Color'])
df3
```

Output:

```
    Age   Eye Color  weight
0   20    Yellow     23.0
1   22    brown      NaN
2   44    black      NaN
```

Comment: if i do that my dataframe ad 5 columns: age_x, age_y, eye color_x, eye color_y, weight. I just want age, eye color and weight.

Comment: @HoyaMiner perhaps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62779180/pandas-merge-unexpectedly-produces-suffixes) an issue like yours was discussed.