# Pandas: Suffixes created on merge with same name columns

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, dataset

I am trying to do a left join using pandas merge however for some reason, I get suffixes on my join even though the series/columns have the same name

penalty_kicks dataframe:
[image]

backup dataframe:[image]

Here is how I am using pd.merge to do the left join as detailed before:

```
penalty_kicks = pd.merge(penalty_kicks,backup, on=['video_name','image_name'],how='left')
```

After that, here is the output table:[image]

Is there a way to just make the data all go into their repective columns?

Comment: Your merging is correct. The values in your columns are different even though they have matching names. You can keep either, subsetting the columns before you merge, or rename them and keep both.

Comment: @alibakhtiari so rename the columns again in order to merge? That did not do the trick. Also what you mean by subsetting the columns?

Comment: @TheBeef the reason this is happening is because for any rows where both the `video_name` and `image_name` are the same for your dataframes `penalty_kicks` and `backup`, the other two columns `penalty kick` and `location` exist in both dataframes. pandas won't know whether to use the `penalty_kick` value from the `penalty_kicks` dataframe or the `backup` dataframe, which is why the suffixes are created to keep information from both dataframes. you can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62779180/pandas-merge-unexpectedly-produces-suffixes) for a further explanation

Comment: @DerekO thank you for this! I have fixed this issue by deleting the columns in original table